# Force windows onto one CPU, and then take over the rest

Tags: windows, operating-system, kernel

I've seen various RTOSes that have this strategy that they have windows boot on one or more CPUs and then run realtime programs on the rest of the CPUs. Any idea how this might be accomplished? Can I let the computer boot off two CPUs and then stop execution on the rest of the CPUs? What documentation should I start looking at? I have enough experience with the linux kernel that I might be able to figure out how to do it under linux, so if there's anything that maps onto linux well that you could describe it in terms of, that'd be fantastic.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that this is usually done with a hypervisor, so that Windows is actually running in a lightweight virtual machine.

Comment: I don't understand why people have downvoted this question.  It seems legit to me.  Please add comments when you downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boot Windows on fewer CPUs than available easily. Run `msconfig.exe`, go to the `Boot` tab, click the `Advanced options...` button, check the `number of processors` box and set the desired number (this is for Windows 7, the exact location for Vista and XP might differ slightly).

But that's just a solution to a very small part of the problem.

You will need to implement a special kernel-mode driver to start those other CPUs (Windows won't let you do that sort of thing from non-kernel-mode code). And you will need to implement a thread scheduler for those CPUs and a bunch of other low-level things... You might want to steal some physical memory (RAM) from Windows as well and implement a memory manager as well and those two may be a very involved thing.

What to read? The Intel/AMD CPU documentation (specifically the APIC part), the x86 Multiprocessor specification from Intel, books on Windows drivers, Windows Internals books, MSDN, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn off Windows on one CPU and expect to run your program as usual because syscalls are serviced by the same CPU that the thread issuing the syscall is issued on. The syscall relies on kernel-mode accessible per-thread data to handle the syscalls, and hence any thread (usermode or kernel-mode) can only run when Windows has performed the per-core initialization of the CPU.

It seems likely that you're writing a super-double-mega-awesome app that really-definitely needs to run, like, super-fast and you want everyone else to get off the core, 'cos then, like, you'll be the totally fastest-est, but you're not really appreciating that if Windows isn't on your core, then you can't use ANY part of Windows on that core either.

If you really do want to do this, you'll have to run as a boot-driver. The boot-driver will be able to reserve one of the cores from being initialized during boot, preventing Windows from "seeing" that core. You can then manually construct your own thread of execution to run on that core, but you'll need to handle paging, memory allocation, scheduling, NUMA, NMI exceptions, page-faulting, and ACPI events yourself. You won't be able to call Windows from that core without bluescreening Windows. You'll be on your own.

What you probably want to do is to lock your thread to a single processor (via SetThreadAffinity) and then up the priority of your thread to the maximum value. When you do so, Windows is still running on your core to service things like pagefaults and hardware interrupts, but no lower priority user-mode thread will run on that core (they'll all move to other cores unless they are also locked to your processor).

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand the question properly. But if you asking for scheduling process to cores then linux can accomplish this using set affinity. Follow this page :

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html